# jquery onchange function is not calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

### i have the following piece of code:

```
function teamAuswaehlen() {
    $.post("Auswahl_Abteilung?_=" + new Date().getTime(), function(data) {
        eintraege = "<div class='col-md-12 col-xs-12'>" +
            "<div class='form-group'>" +
            "<select class='form-control' id='teams'  title='Wählen Sie hier ihre Teamansicht'>"
        if (data.length > 1) {
            $("#kalenderAuswahl .modal-body").empty();



            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value) {
                eintraege += "<option id='" + value.Team_ID + "'>" + value.TE_Kurzbezeichnung + "| " + value.TE_Langbezeichnung + "</option>";
            });
            eintraege += "</select>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>";
        }
        if (data.length > 1) {
            $("#kalenderAuswahl .modal-body").append(eintraege);
            $("#kalenderAuswahl").modal("show");
        }

    }).done(function() {
        $("#teams").change(function() {
            getId(this);
        });
    });
}
```

The Modal is build dynamicly at the start of the programm.
So the onchange event i want to call if a user change the select box is store in the done block.
But if i trie the code, nothing happens so the onchange event is not fired.

**So how can i handle that ?**

Comment: read you code line by line and fix errors , check this : $.post("Auswahl_Abteilung?_="+new Date().getTime(),function(data){ or $.each(JSON.parse(data),function(key,value){

Comment: @oleevier I can't see any error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code snippet for your change event.

```
$('body').on('change', '#teams', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do your stuff
});
```

You can write this change event code in below section

1. Before body tag end Or
2. You can write in `$(document).ready(function() {})`

Answer (score 0):

- you can remove done method and paste your code to body.
- select event with body tag as like `$('body').on('change', '#teams'`

or

just use like this `$('body').on('change', '#teams'` in done method.

Answer (score 0):

No need to place code in done().place the following code anywhere in  tag

```
$(document).on('change','#teams',function() {
   getId(this);
});
```